# How to add a vertical and horizontal scroll bar in a JTextArea to view complete file - JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am trying to add a horizontal and vertical scroll bar to read the entire text file after opening it. Because the way I have it structured the file is only partially displayed. Please see the image below and code. Is there something that I am doing incorrectly? Updated Code

[image: Updated picture]

```
  public class OpenFile {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                OpenFile window = new OpenFile();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public OpenFile() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
    jTextArea1.setBounds(15, 45, 398, 183);
    //frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jTextArea1));


    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Read Text");
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            String nameFile = f.getAbsolutePath();

            try {

                FileReader reader = new FileReader(nameFile);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                jTextArea1.read(br, null);
                br.close();
                jTextArea1.requestFocus();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }


        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(15, 16, 115, 29);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
}
}
```

I have no clue why it is displaying as shown in the picture. Please advise.

Comment: Put your JTextArea in a JScrollPane:  `frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jTextArea1));`  And you really should not set the layout to null. I’m guessing the content pane’s default layout manager (a BorderLayout) is sufficient, but if it’s not, you will be better off specifying a layout explicitly.

Comment: If I do that, it removes the jTextArea1. Is there a reason why that it goes away? Please see modified code.

Comment: Remove `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);` and the scrollable text area should become visible.

Comment: Whenever I do that, the JTextField goes away. Please see updated code along with picture.

Comment: Though you don’t show this in your code, I assume you are doing `frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton)`.  Since the layout is a BorderLayout, and you don’t specify a constraint, BorderLayout assumes you want to add the component in the center of the BorderLayout, but since there can only be one center child component, that code *replaces* the JScrollPane with the new center component.  The solution is specify a constraint, so the button is not added as the BorderLayout’s center component:  `frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`.

Comment: I have provided the entire code that I have except the imports. It makes sense what you mentioned about the BorderLayout, however it does not display the JTextField? Please see updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(jTextArea1);
scrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

And correct the position of the JButton. Try this code:

```
public class OpenFile {

private JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            OpenFile window = new OpenFile();
            window.frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}

public OpenFile() {
initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
jTextArea1.setText("Here is a text ... ");
jTextArea1.setBounds(10, 39, 402, 199);

frame.getContentPane().add(jTextArea1);

JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(jTextArea1);
scrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
    ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollBar);
scrollBar.setBounds(13, 39, 413, 214);

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Read the text");
btnNewButton.setBounds(149, 10, 130, 21);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String nameFile = f.getAbsolutePath();

        try {

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(nameFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            jTextArea1.read(br, null);
            br.close();
            jTextArea1.requestFocus();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much! Is there a way to make the textfield increase to full size when maximizing the JFrame when the program runs?

Comment: If I don't mistake the JTextArea can't be autoresized if it contains JScrollPanes. But, whithout them, the JTextArea will resize automatically.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Consider giving the number of rows and colums as constructor arguments when initializing the JTextArea object.

Comment: How would I go about doing so?

Comment: JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea(5, 30); 5 rows and 30 columns